# Extending and delegating Swift framework to Objective-c class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a project from 2015 which I'm updating to iOS10 (2016 technology).
One of the classes the old programmer used is extending from a swift written framework.

The problem is that I'm receiving a few errors like:
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'XLPagerTabStripViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UIPageViewControllerDelegate'?

and

Cannot find interface declaration for 'XLBarPagerTabStripViewController', superclass of 'MLHistoryViewController'

My question is... How do I extend a class from swift based code in objective-c? Am I importing the correct way as described below?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MLOngoingReservationsViewController.h"
#import "MLPastReservationsViewController.h"
#import <XLPagerTabStrip/XLPagerTabStrip-Swift.h>
#import <XLPagerTabStrip/XLPagerTabStrip-umbrella.h>



@interface MLHistoryViewController : XLBarPagerTabStripViewController <XLPagerTabStripViewControllerDelegate> {
    BOOL finishedLoadingOnGoingReservations;
    BOOL finishedLoadingPastReservations;

    MLOngoingReservationsViewController *ongoingReservations;
    MLPastReservationsViewController *pastReservations;
}
```

Comment: XLPagerTabStripViewControllerDelegate, is this is extended from : NSObjectProtocol?

Comment: I believe so, this framework the developer got from here: https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Comment: They have updated their Code I guess. You need to go through their changes to integrate into yours. I see that they renamed `XLBarPagerTabStripViewController` to `PagerTabStripViewController`.